# Ubuntu 22.04 Reboot&poweroff frozen after update

Tags: reboot, reset

Please help me!

I use Ubuntu 22.04 and after update 6 August reboot and poweroff did not work .really after that Ubuntu frozen and didn't power off.

Comment: type "sudo poweroff"

Comment: you'll be surprised at how fault tolerant Ubuntu actually is. Just use the power on/off button on your device (may need to press and hold) and then turn it back on. This has worked well for me in the past. After the PC reboots, suggest you use the normal means to restart it.